# SEVERE: Error loading JavaScript from [http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js] when loading a simple page in HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit

When loading link :http://pdfcast.org/login in HtmlUnit using following code

```
    webclient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME_16);
    webclient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webclient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    webclient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webclient.setRefreshHandler(new ThreadedRefreshHandler());
    HtmlPage currentPage = webclient.getPage("http://pdfcast.org/login");
```

error occured:

```
Sep 26, 2012 10:04:38 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage loadExternalJavaScriptFile
SEVERE: Error loading JavaScript from [http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js].
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 504 Gateway Time-out for http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.throwFailingHttpStatusCodeExceptionIfNecessary(WebClient.java:542)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadJavaScriptFromUrl(HtmlPage.java:1041)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:981)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:366)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$1.execute(HtmlScript.java:234)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:244)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:607)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:329)
```

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: I have never used `HtmlUnit`, but from their documentation, you might want to look at [setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(boolean)).

Comment: thank you jw r.i will take alook

Comment: I have the same problem for other pages like : http://www.sportmediaset.mediaset.it/

Answer (score 0):

It works with htmlunit 2.13

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ThreadedRefreshHandler;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class KUKU {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME_16);
            webclient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webclient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
            webclient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webclient.setRefreshHandler(new ThreadedRefreshHandler());
            HtmlPage currentPage = webclient.getPage("http://pdfcast.org/login");
            System.out.println(currentPage.asText());

    }

}
```

This is the output

> 07/11/2013 14:53:33
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   07/11/2013 14:53:34
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered:
>   'application/x-javascript'. 07/11/2013 14:53:34
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   07/11/2013 14:53:35
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   07/11/2013 14:53:35
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered:
>   'application/x-javascript'. 07/11/2013 14:53:36
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   07/11/2013 14:53:36
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   07/11/2013 14:53:36
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   07/11/2013 14:53:36
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   07/11/2013 14:53:37
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered:
>   'application/x-javascript'. 07/11/2013 14:53:37
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   07/11/2013 14:53:37
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error WARNING:
>   CSS error:
>   'http://pdfcast-data.appspot.com/css/style_fb_bt_apl_star.min.css?1'
>   [251:69] Error in expression. (Invalid token ".". Was expecting one
>   of: , , , , , , , "-",
>   "=", ")".) 07/11/2013 14:53:37
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered:
>   'application/x-javascript'. 07/11/2013 14:53:38
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered:
>   'application/x-javascript'. Login and Registration Search Upload PDF
>   F.A.Q. Contact Us Facebook Connect Google Login Sign In Register Login
>   If you already have a PDFCast account, you can sign in below. Username
>   Password    LOGIN Forget your password? Register Don't have an account
>   yet? Sign up now by completing form below. Username    Password
>   Repeat Password    Email
>
> Enter the words above (reload image)
>
> REGISTER 3rd Party You can sign in with your Facebook or Google
>   account. It's easier and more secure. Click logo below.
>
> Browse | DMCA Guidelines | Terms of Use | Privacy Notice | Contact |
>   Facebook © Copyright 2013 PDFCast.org
>
> 0.0255 - 4.11MB

btw:
BrowserVersion.CHROME_16 is deprecated.
Use BrowserVersion.CHROME instead